# How to remove a value based on a key from a Dictionary<uint, List<uint>>?

Tags: c#, dictionary

[This is the errror message I get with the `k` variable.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7kdP.png)
I have a dictionary in my code in the format of `Dictionary<uint, List<uint>>`. I want to iterate over the Dictionary and remove items based on the **value** and not the key initially. Then I want to remove the **key** once all the **values** in the key are removed. I am unsure on how to do this.

I used a foreach loop to iterate but it does not seem to work. Can someone give me guidance with a pseudocode on how to do this.

The `k` is having issues.

The code I used.

```
List<uint> todel = MyList.Keys.Where(k => k.Contains(Idx)).ToList();
todel.ForEach(k => MyList.Remove(k));
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest posting the code that didn't work for you. It will help others guide you in the right direction.

Comment: You cant change a collection while using a `foreach` loop over it. Get a collection of keys, then iterate over the keys, looking up the entry each iteration.

Comment: @DStanley I passed the code above which I used. It is giving me errors. Can you guide me please

Comment: OK that looks fine to me, other then you have two different variable names - `MyList` and `dictionary`. Is that the problem?

Comment: @Igor I am new to C# and would appreciate if you could give me a pseudocode on how to do it.

Comment: *but it does not seem to work.* - what does happen? Does not work isn't much of a bug description. Does it give an error? Not do what you expected? Not do anything at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"I want to iterate over the Dictionary and remove items based on the value and not the key initially. Then I want to remove the key once all the values in the key are removed."*

Here's one way to do it, if I understand correctly:

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> source = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
source.Add(1, new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
source.Add(2, new List<int> { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7});
source.Add(3, new List<int> { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10});

foreach (var key in source.Keys.ToList()) // ToList forces a copy so we're not modifying the collection
{
    source[key].RemoveAll(v => v < 6); // or any other criterion

    if (!source[key].Any())
    {
        source.Remove(key);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Key count: " + source.Keys.Count());
foreach (var key in source.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key: " + key + " Count: " + source[key].Count());
}
```

Output:

> Key count: 2
>   Key: 2 Count: 2
>   Key: 3 Count: 5

Comment: If I want to remove each value individually starting from 1 in the list to 5. Fore example, for Key 1, I want to remove value 1, then value 2 and value 3 till value 5 one by one, I am unsure on how to do it? Here it only removes values lesser than 6.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the problematic line:

```
List<uint> todel = MyList.Keys.Where(k => k.Contains(Idx)).ToList();
```

Try something like this

```
List<uint> todel = MyList.Keys.Where(k => k == Idx).ToList();
```

k is not a list, it is of type uint.

If you want to remove the records value of which contains Idx, then try this

```
List<uint> todel = MyList.Where(k => k.Value.Contains(Idx)).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
```